# You have 1 pending migrations: 20140415221104 CreateBoxesAndBoxesSuppliers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I execute rake comand this is what I get:

```
    You have 1 pending migrations:
    20140415221104 CreateBoxesAndBoxesSuppliers 
    Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

Comment: Post your migration file `20140415221104_create_boxes_and_boxes_suppliers.rb`

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, all you need to do is Run `rake db:migrate`.

As per the error, `Mysql2::Error: Table 'boxes' already exists`,
you already created `boxes` table from another migration and with `20140415221104 CreateBoxesAndBoxesSuppliers` migration you are trying to create `boxes` again.

You should not be creating `boxes` table again in `20140415221104 CreateBoxesAndBoxesSuppliers` migration.

Comment: What error do you get? Is this the only error you get? If not, then please share the complete error log. Also, when you did `rake db:migrate` what output did you get, was the migration successful? Please share

Comment: This is what i get with the rake db:migrate '==  CreateBoxesAndBoxesSuppliers: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:boxes, {:options=>"DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci"})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:'

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Table 'boxes' already exists: CREATE TABLE `boxes` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `description` text, `price` float, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL, `box_image_file_name` varchar(255), `box_image_content_type` varchar(255), `box_image_file_size` int(11),

Comment: `box_image_updated_at` datetime) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci/home/alvaro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'

Comment: @user3557451 it means,you are already having a table called boxes in your DB.Once cross check.

Comment: @user3557451 Can you share the migration file `CreateBoxesAndBoxesSuppliers`. Please update it in the question and DO Not post in comments.